# Use recursion to build matlab structure of dendrogram

Tags: matlab, recursion

I want to use recursion in MATLAB to generate a linked structure that replicates a dendrogram.

For example, a very simple dendrogram might be represented in a matrix generated from a call to the `linkage` function.

```
1 2 1.0
4 3 1.5
```

Where the first linkage is between items 1 and 2, with a distance and 1.0, and the second linkage is between item 3 and the merger of 1 and 2, denoted by 4, with a distance of 1.5

Thus, from this matrix I would want a structure that would be something like node1.children = {node2, node3}, and node2.children = {node4, node5}. Where the leaf notes are node3 item3, node4 is item 1, and node5 is item 2.

How would I write a recursive function that would generate this type of structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a `node` class that derives from `handle`.

```
classdef node<handle

    properties
        children
    end

    methods
        % a method that parses the incoming matrix and hands it over to its
        % children to do the same
    end
end
```

The advantage of doing it like this is that in children you can save it like `obj.children{end+1}=newChild` and what you are saving is just a reference to the child because you derived from `handle`.

Comment: Not to forget that's the only way for more complex structures where a child can have several parents.

Comment: Could you write out what the constructor might look like? I am having some trouble figuring out how to parse the input matrix that contains the linkage information. Thanks!

Comment: @user1027169 For that I would need further information about the linkage matrix. Especially how you compute the index for the merger. But basically you just have to find out which nodes are leafs and then from there start building the tree by adding the parent nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mention to have a node class as subclass of handle.

You could do it very elegantly using this strategy:

1. prepare an empty list to contain ALL nodes (cell?)
2. when you read a line find if the nodes are in the list - otherwise make them and add them
3. add the child to the parent
4. repeat from 1. till list is done
5. now take root node from list - it will be in the structure you want